# Number of connections and realtime traffic not matching

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress

I must have done some wrong config and hence my connections are getting choked.

```
# netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 established)
      1 Foreign
      1 LAST_ACK
      2 FIN_WAIT2
      5 FIN_WAIT1
      8 LISTEN
      9 SYN_RECV
    155 ESTABLISHED
   2551 TIME_WAIT
```

While Google Analytics shows me that realtime traffic is 1100 to 1200.

php-fpm status page shows:

```
pool    www
process manager static
start time  06/Jan/2017:14:34:42 -0500
start since 738
accepted conn   1134
listen queue    0
max listen queue    0
listen queue len    40000
idle processes  399
active processes    1
total processes 400
max active processes    10
max children reached    0
slow requests   0
```

I have a pretty busy site and I'm worried that I've screwed up the settings to limit the connections. Please guide me.

Comment: Why do you think that "connections are getting choked"? I see no evidence of it here.

Comment: Usually, my traffic gets higher during the day and there's a curve. But today, it's been flat hovering at around 1200 throughout the day. Hence the concern. This is impossible. Can you help?